# How to prefer longer intervals in weighted interval scheduling

Tags: python, algorithm

[Weighted interval scheduling](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2017/cmsc451-0101/Lects/lect10-dp-intv-sched.pdf) has a fast solution that is reasonably easy to implement. Here is some code in python:

```
# A class to store a Job
class Job:
    def __init__(self, start, finish, profit):
        self.start = start
        self.finish = finish
        self.profit = profit
 
 
# Function to perform a binary search on the given jobs, which are sorted
# by finish time. The function returns the index of the last job, which
# doesn't conflict with the given job, i.e., whose finish time is
# less than or equal to the given job's start time.
def findLastNonConflictingJob(jobs, n):
 
    # search space
    (low, high) = (0, n)
 
    # iterate till the search space is exhausted
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if jobs[mid].finish <= jobs[n].start:
            if jobs[mid + 1].finish <= jobs[n].start:
                low = mid + 1
            else:
                return mid
        else:
            high = mid - 1
 
    # return the negative index if no non-conflicting job is found
    return -1
 
 
# Function to print the non-overlapping jobs involved in maximum profit
# using dynamic programming
def findMaxProfitJobs(jobs):
 
    # sort jobs in increasing order of their finish times
    jobs.sort(key=lambda x: x.finish)
    print([(jobs[i].start, jobs[i].finish) for i in range(len(jobs))])
 
    # get the number of jobs
    n = len(jobs)
 
    # `maxProfit[i]` stores the maximum profit possible for the first `i` jobs, and
    # `tasks[i]` stores the index of jobs involved in the maximum profit
    maxProfit = [None] * n
    tasks = [[] for _ in range(n)]
 
    # initialize `maxProfit[0]` and `tasks[0]` with the first job
    maxProfit[0] = jobs[0].profit
    tasks[0].append(0)
 
    # fill `tasks[]` and `maxProfit[]` in a bottom-up manner
    for i in range(1, n):
 
        # find the index of the last non-conflicting job with the current job
        index = findLastNonConflictingJob(jobs, i)
 
        # include the current job with its non-conflicting jobs
        currentProfit = jobs[i].profit
        if index != -1:
            currentProfit += maxProfit[index]
 
        # if including the current job leads to the maximum profit so far
        if maxProfit[i - 1] <= currentProfit:
            maxProfit[i] = currentProfit
 
            if index != -1:
                tasks[i] = tasks[index]
            tasks[i].append(i)
 
        # excluding the current job leads to the maximum profit so far
        else:
            tasks[i] = tasks[i - 1][:]
            maxProfit[i] = maxProfit[i - 1]
 
    # `maxProfit[n-1]` stores the maximum profit
    print("The maximum profit is", maxProfit[n - 1])
 
    # `tasks[n-1]` stores the index of jobs involved in the maximum profit
    print("The jobs involved in the maximum profit are", end=' ')
    for i in tasks[n - 1]:
        print((jobs[i].start, jobs[i].finish, jobs[i].profit), end=' ')
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = [
        Job(0, 3, 4), Job(0, 7, 8), Job(4, 7, 4)
    ]
 
    findMaxProfitJobs(jobs)
```

The code outputs:

```
The jobs involved in the maximum profit are (0, 3, 4) (4, 7, 4)
```

In this case the two weights of the two intervals (0,3) and (4,7) sum to the same value as the weight of the interval (0, 7).  When this happens I would like the algorithm to return the single longer interval but this code returns the two shorter ones.

How can the code/algorithm be modified to prefer longer intervals as a tie breaker?

Comment: https://www.techiedelight.com/weighted-interval-scheduling-problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than longer intervals, the proper criteria would be the lower number of intervals.  So we are solving using two criteria:

1. Provide maximum weight (profit)
2. Using the minimum number of jobs

Note: an issue with the current code is the use of shallow copy rather than deepcopy i.e.

```
 tasks[i] = tasks[i - 1][:]  # Shallow copy
 tasks[i] = deepcopy(tasks[i-1]  # Deep copy
```

Use of shallow copy while providing the correct profit provides incorrect jobs in more complex cases.

**Code**

```
from copy import deepcopy

# A class to store a Job
class Job:
    def __init__(self, start, finish, profit):
        self.start = start
        self.finish = finish
        self.profit = profit
 
 
# Function to perform a binary search on the given jobs, which are sorted
# by finish time. The function returns the index of the last job, which
# doesn't conflict with the given job, i.e., whose finish time is
# less than or equal to the given job's start time.
def findLastNonConflictingJob(jobs, n):
 
    # search space
    (low, high) = (0, n)
 
    # iterate till the search space is exhausted
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if jobs[mid].finish <= jobs[n].start:
            if jobs[mid + 1].finish <= jobs[n].start:
                low = mid + 1
            else:
                return mid
        else:
            high = mid - 1
 
    # return the negative index if no non-conflicting job is found
    return -1
 
 
# Function to print the non-overlapping jobs involved in maximum profit
# using dynamic programming
def findMaxProfitJobs(jobs):
 
    # sort jobs in increasing order of their finish times
    jobs.sort(key=lambda x: x.finish)
    print([(jobs[i].start, jobs[i].finish) for i in range(len(jobs))])
 
    # get the number of jobs
    n = len(jobs)
 
    # `maxProfit[i]` is a tuple containing the maximum profit possible for the 
    # first `i` jobs and the negative of the number of jobs to achieve 
    # this profit. We use negative intervals since when looking for max, 
    # the number of intervals will be minimized as a tie-breaker on profit
    # `tasks[i]` stores the index of jobs involved in the maximum profit
    maxProfit = [None] * n
    tasks = [[] for _ in range(n)]
 
    # initialize `maxProfit[0]` and `tasks[0]` with the first job
    maxProfit[0] = (jobs[0].profit, -1)
    tasks[0].append(0)
 
    # fill `tasks[]` and `maxProfit[]` in a bottom-up manner
    for i in range(1, n):
 
        # find the index of the last non-conflicting job with the current job
        index = findLastNonConflictingJob(jobs, i)
 
        # include the current job with its non-conflicting jobs
        currentProfit = (jobs[i].profit, -1)   # (profit, negative of number of jobs)
        if index != -1:
            # current tuple of profit and negative of number of intervals
            currentProfit = (currentProfit[0] + maxProfit[index][0], 
                             currentProfit[1] + maxProfit[index][1])
            
 
        # if including the current job leads to the maximum profit so far
        if maxProfit[i - 1] <= currentProfit:
            # comparison of tuple based upon profit and number of jobs
            maxProfit[i] = currentProfit
 
            if index != -1:
                tasks[i] = deepcopy(tasks[index])
            tasks[i].append(i)
 
        # excluding the current job leads to the maximum profit so far
        else:
            tasks[i] = deepcopy(tasks[i - 1])
            maxProfit[i] = maxProfit[i - 1]
 
    # `maxProfit[n-1]` stores the maximum profit
    print("The maximum profit is", maxProfit[n - 1])
 
    # `tasks[n-1]` stores the index of jobs involved in the maximum profit
    print("The jobs involved in the maximum profit are", end=' ')
    
    for i in tasks[n - 1]:
        print((jobs[i].start, jobs[i].finish, jobs[i].profit), end=' ')
    print()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test 1
    print('Test 1')
    jobs = [
        Job(0, 3, 4), Job(0, 7, 8), Job(4, 7, 4)
    ]
    
    findMaxProfitJobs(jobs)
    
    # Test 2
    print('\nTest 2')
    jobs = [
        Job(2, 2, 50), Job(3, 5, 20), Job(6, 19, 100), Job(2, 100, 200)
    ]
 
    findMaxProfitJobs(jobs)
```

**Output**

```
Test 1
[(0, 3), (0, 7), (4, 7)]
The maximum profit is (8, -1)
Tasks [[0], [1], [1]]
The jobs involved in the maximum profit are (0, 7, 8) 

Test 2
[(2, 2), (3, 5), (6, 19), (2, 100)]
The maximum profit is (250, -2)
Tasks [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 3]]
The jobs involved in the maximum profit are (2, 2, 50) (2, 100, 200)
```

Comment: This is a really great answer. Thank you!